# Using an android non-rooted as a wifi adapter

Tags: wifi, firewalls, android

I want to use an android phone as a wifi adapter, and I was wondering if it added security to my connection. The phone has a complicated long password, it also have an app store firewall (noroot firewall).

I am not sure if it changes something, but I wanted to find out.

Comment: Your post had been enough good for an upvote, but I won't reward bad writing quality. So, you got an edit suggestion, instead of my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your set up is your phone is connected to the internet somehow (4G/3G/wifi) and then you are using your phone as a wifi hotspot (aka wifi tethering), so other devices can connect to your phone and use your phone's internet connection.

This doesn't increase the network security in any way.  If the network connection your phone is using is compromised (e.g., unencrypted wifi is visible to anyone in your wifi radio range, or encrypted wifi or 3G/4G connection that people nearby can't eavesdrop, though the ISP can eavesdrop) then they can still intercept and/or modify all your traffic from devices tethered to your phone (though they won't be able to decrypt or subtly modify encrypted traffic like via HTTPS).  It doesn't matter if the connection between your phone and the device is strong (e.g., WPA2), the encrypted wifi traffic between your device and your phone gets decrypted at your phone and then is sent over the insecure network (as if it came from your phone instead of a device tethered to your phone).

It potentially does decrease the security, if your phone is connected to a WiFi network with WPA2 and a strong passphrase, but your wifi hotspot uses no encryption or a very weak encryption (e.g., WEP) and a weak passphrase.  This allows an attacker to eavesdrop the connection between your device and your phone, where they wouldn't have been able to eavesdrop the connection between your device and the wifi network with WPA2.

If you are security conscious, you potentially could increase the local network security by routing all your internet traffic on your phone through a VPN.  This would allow you to connect to a weak local network (e.g., wifi with no password in a public place) and encrypt all your traffic between you and your VPN server.  Note your unencrypted traffic (e.g., not HTTPS) will still be visible to an eavesdropper at your VPN server and beyond (that is between the VPN server and the server you are talking to on the internet).  (Granted you could also just make every device connect to your VPN directly as well).

The point of the firewall is to protect your phone from incoming network attacks and/or limit the network ability of malware you may have inadvertently installed.  It doesn't affect the security of your connection.

Comment: Wow that's very informative!

I wasn't specific enough, i have a modem/router connected to a second  router that i use as a slave, the slave one is the one i connect my range extender to, then i use my android as a wifi connecter via USB thetering. 

I'm doing this because for some reason someone was connecting to my wifi network, and also another time some some kind of adware had infected my modem/router and anyone using a phone on the network was redirected to different phishing websites whenever they'd try to access a website.

Phone and computer both have a vpn on different servers.

Comment: Modem/router to router slave to range extender to phone (vpn) to computer (vpn)